# $_POST PHP UPDATE errors and not sending options

Tags: php, post, mysqli, isset

I am trying $_POST an UPDATE to the following mysql table:
**Note:** there are 3  dropdowns: status, category and access

```
app_generalData
---------------
app_id
table
status_id
category_id
tags
access_id
```

Resulting tests with print_r($_POST) and echo(s) 's ensure the form $_POST is working:

```
Array ( 
        [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 100000
        [app_id] => 1 
        [title] => Nothing Special 
        [status] => 
        [category] => 
        [tags] => new tag 
        [access] => 
        [update] => Update )
```

**Data from the form.**

- **ID:** 1
- **Title:** Nothing Special
- **Status:**
- **Category:**
- **Tags:** new tag
- **Access:**

### Resulting Error message:

```
Error querying database for General Data.
```

### Desired result(s):

1. $_POST items updating in the db

### Snippet for UPDATE:

```
// Post the UPDATE to app_generalData
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  // print_r($_POST);
  // echo '<br />';

// Connect to the database
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Grab the data from the POST

  // General Data
  $app_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['app_id']));
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['title']));
  $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['status']));
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['category']));
  $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['tags']));
  $access = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['access']));

// Confirm success with the user

    echo '<h1>Data from the form.</h1><br />';
    echo 'ID: ' . $app_id .'<br />';
    echo 'Title: ' . $title .'<br />';
    echo 'Status: ' . $status .'<br />';
    echo 'Category: ' . $category .'<br />';
    echo 'Tags: ' . $tags .'<br />';
    echo 'Access: ' . $access .'<br />';

    echo '<br />';

// Write the data to the database
  $query = "UPDATE      app_generalData
            SET         title = $title,
                        status_id = $status,
                        category_id = $category,
                        tags = $tags,
                        access_id = $access
            WHERE       app_id = $app_id
            ";

  mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
        or die('Error querying database for General Data.');

// close MySQL
  mysqli_close($dbc);

  exit();
}
else {
  echo 'Please enter all details below.';
}
```

Comment: Have you echoed the `mysqli_error`? What does the actual error say?

Comment: @Rasclatt Thanks for your suggestion. I've given you an up vote because your suggestion lead me to thinking outside the box. When I ran **print_r** on **$query**, I could see that the SET items weren't written with quotes around the $var(s). I'll post the corrected edit for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get `mysql_errors` i'd suggest the first thing you do if the problem is not found by just looking at the code, is echoing out the query.

What seems to be your problem here is you are not surrounding your string in `''` (quotes) like:

```
$query = "UPDATE      app_generalData
    SET         title = '$title',
                status_id = '$status',
                category_id = '$category',
                tags = '$tags',
                access_id = '$access'
    WHERE       app_id = '$app_id'
    ";
```

Comment: Thanks for you for your response. It came through just as I was posting my own correction as I'd just tested & noticed the same thing. I've now tested your edit & it seems to be working with the way you wrote it as well. I've given you a up-vote, but...could you maybe given me an idea why my <select> options aren't coming through in the $_POST? Is there something else that needs to be added to <select><option> tags to include them $_POST?

Comment: Tough to tell what is wrong without the html code of your <select> but you are better of "closing" this question by choosing a correct answer and reopening another one with your exact code since it's a different problem than this one.

Answer (score 0):

After running a `print_r($query)`, I was able to notice that the query was posting the following:

```
UPDATE app_generalData
SET title = Nothing Special,
    status_id = ,
    category_id = ,
    tags = new tag,
    access_id = 
WHERE app_id = 1
```

Reason for error: there are no marks (" or ') around the values?

Working solution:

I've updated the query to the following

```
UPDATE app_generalData
SET title = '".$title."',
    status_id = '".$status."',
    category_id = '".$category."',
    tags = '".$tags."',
    access_id = '".$access."'
WHERE app_id = $app_id
            ";
```